# Why do i have several flexipage instances?

Tags: flexipages

I have 3 flexipage instances and cant understand why ?

> Approval_Process_Instance_Record_Page.flexipage
>   Approval_Process_Instance_Record_Page1.flexipage
>   Approval_Process_Instance_Record_Page2.flexipage

And where i can find what is default ?

Comment: I guess you must have defined multiple layouts of your Approval_Process_Instance_Record_Page.

Comment: Go to Object Manager for that object, there should be a section for what Lightning Pages are assigned to the object.